# Getting a decimal number after @ with regex

Tags: regex

I am looking to get a regex pattern that can get a decimal number after `@`  space included. So in the string `hello I am a @ 23.43 string`, it will return `23.43`.

Sorry I am struggling with regex and understanding it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try:

```regex
(?<=@ )-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?
```

### Demo

The quantity `(?<=@ )` is called a positive *lookbehind*, because it asserts that what precedes the decimal (or integer) number is `@` followed by a single space.

Edit: Here is a JavaScript solution:

```js
var input = "hello I am a @ 23.43 string";
var num = input.match(/@\s*(-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)/)[1];
console.log(num);
```

Comment: For completeness, the regex should allow `-` (minus sign).

Comment: In my recent experience Safari does not support look behinds. Is that true and will this pose an issue. Sorry about not giving that context.

Comment: @ThomasByy What actual language/tool are you using for your regex problem?  I can give other answers, but I would need to know this.

Comment: I am using Javascript (React). I wasn't aware that effected your answer sorry

Comment: @ThomasByy Check the updated answer for a solution which doesn't rely on lookarounds.